# Handling user authorization in istio

Tags: authorization, istio, istio-gateway

I have an `auth service` that checks the validity of jwt token in `req.headers.Authorization`, and i have another API service to do a CRUD operation for a `customer` entity, that will require a valid JWT on every request to said API service. And all of this is wrapped inside `kubernetes cluster + istio`. What i am currently doing is like this

1. Client is requesting to `POST /customer` with a JWT as `headers.Authorization`
2. The `POST /customer` API service on the backend will then communicate with the `auth service` by passing the JWT to check its validity
3. If it's not valid then return some token error response
4. If it is valid, then do the create customer operation, and save the data to the database

While this is working fine, i find that i am repeating this `auth checks` on every endpoint, i can of course set up a middleware on that same service that will do the checks by intercepting the incoming request before it reaches the `controller`.

I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this `middleware` approach in `istio` instead of writing it on the service itself.

What i would like to achieve

1. Client is requesting to `POST /customer` with a JWT as `headers.Authorization`
2. **The `istio sidecar(?)/ingress gateway` will catch this request, and send (redirect) it over to the auth service to check first, before passing it to its destination**
3. If it's not valid then return some token error response
4. If it is valid, then then pass it on to its original destination

Can istio do this? I have read through the istio documentation on [Authorization](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/), but i don't think it explains the things that i want to achieve here

Comment: Assuming you have your own auth service, you can use webassembly to actieve this. Examples : https://github.com/solo-io/proxy-runtime/tree/master/examples/auth , https://github.com/proxy-wasm/proxy-wasm-rust-sdk

Answer (score 1):

End user authentication using JWT is definitely possible in Istio.
You may be looking for this article which explains JWT authentication and authorization with Istio.

See https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-jwt/

Comment: as i have mentioned, i read that too already, but the whole document doesn't seem to provide any example for my scenario, the one that you pointed out is using `jwks.json`, which i think is a different scenario/approach

Comment: Well "usually" identity providers support the jwks approach. If it is only about validating a JWT token, this means a less complex setup without explicit redirection to an auth service. If possible, and it is not a non-standard approach...

Comment: i see, hmm so cmiiw, what you're trying to say is that i should provide the jkws approach in my auth api service, and then use the jwks.json file generated from it in the istio setup?

Comment: No I meant if you use an authentication provider (e.g., Auth0) which has the option to provide jwks you don't even need a separate auth service. And only if this is not possible the Auth service might provide a jkws for Istio's use. Or is your "Auth service" an own implementation of a authentication provider?

Comment: my Auth service, is an own implementation, and no i don't use auth provider such as Auth0

Comment: Ok well then you might try providing that jwks if possible. I suppose that service uses some kind of library which might make an implementation of an jwks interface easier

Comment: Yeah i guess, its either i switch into using an Auth Provider, or implement JKWS in my own-implement-auth-service. Does this also means that istio doesn't support the explicit-redirect approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232497/discussion-between-littlechad-and-user140547).

Comment: Just saw this post . We also did centralized JWT validation at istio ingress gateway using Keycloak  .

Answer (score 0):

I believe, what you are trying to achieve, is possible with [request routing](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/). Basically, chatch a request based on a header, and route it to a service.

Comment: i think this will only redirect the request without passing the request through to the original request on success. Based on my question, this will only fulfill #1 and #2, as i think it will never go to #3 and or #4